# Is there an identity function?

Tags: python, theano

Suppose I have a Theano symbol `x` and I run the following code.

```
x.name = "x"
y = x
y.name = "y"
```

Of course `x.name` is then `"y"`. **Is there an identity function that lets me do something like the following?**

```
x.name = "x"
y = T.identity(x)
y.name = "y"
```

The expected behavior is that `y` is now seen to be a function of `x`, and they are both properly named. Of course the Theano compiler would simply merge the symbols because `y` is just `x`.

The reason I am asking this is because I have a situation like the following, where `filter` and `feature` are Theano symbols and `nonlinear` is either `True` or `False`.

```
activation = T.dot(feature, filter)
activation.name = "activation"
response = T.nnet.sigmoid(activation) if nonlinear else activation
response.name = "response"
```

The problem is that in the case of `nonlinear` being `False`, my `activation` symbol gets the name `"response"`.

I can fix this by working around the problem:

```
activation = T.dot(feature, filter)
activation.name = "activation"
if nonlinear:
    response = T.nnet.sigmoid(activation)
    response.name = "response"
else:
    response = activation
    response.name = "activation&response"
```

But an identity function would be much more elegant:

```
activation = T.dot(feature, filter)
activation.name = "activation"
response = T.nnet.sigmoid(activation) if nonlinear else T.identity(activation)
response.name = "response"
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Theano, but would deepcopy help?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik No, Theano symbols are symbolic math expressions, not regular Python data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`copy(name=None)` function](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor._tensor_py_operators.copy) on tensors is what you want.

The first example becomes this:

```
x.name = "x"
y = x.copy("y")
```

The second example becomes this:

```
activation = T.dot(feature, filter)
activation.name = "activation"
response = T.nnet.sigmoid(activation) if nonlinear else activation.copy()
response.name = "response"
```